# Attempting to access Folder in Terminal (Name has spaces)

Tags: linux, terminal

This might seem like an dumb mistake, but I'm trying to access my files in a folder (Final Project), but the name of the folder has a space in between it so im curious on how to do so. I've tried commands such as:

```
cd ./Final Project
cd ../Final Project
cd ~/Final Project
cd ~/Final/Project
```

[Screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEIh9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type:

```
cd Final\ Project/
```

You could also quote it like so:

```
cd "Final Project"
```

You can actually use `TAB` to your advantage. Type:

```
cd Fin<TAB>
```

and your terminal might auto-fill the name.

Comment: Thank you it seems like all of those methods worked out perfectly!

Comment: Awesome. Feel free to put closure to your question by marking this or any other answer that may come after this as accepted. There is usually a tick mark by the answer to mark it accepted. It's optional.